# Is there a high-res version of our logo somewhere?

Tags: discussion, design

I'd love to put our logo on our [Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/118962814909394/) page (assuming that's permitted by SE policy).  Is there somewhere a higher res version of our logo can be found?

I suppose could always take a photo of the T-shirt I was sent... :)

Comment: The footer says something explicitly about the logo, it belongs to SE... I think they tolerate it because the group is not a business...

Comment: Kinda need [this page of logos](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos) but with travel....can't seem to find it tho :/

Comment: [Our sprites are here, out of interest](http://cdn.sstatic.net/travel/img/sprites.png?v=6)

Answer (score 4):

After asking @jmac, one of the CMs and having a chat with some of the other mods, basically it comes down to the rules in the [Trademark page](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> The logos associated with Stack Exchange Inc. and any Stack Exchange
>   site are a trademark. The purpose of trademark law is to prevent
>   consumers from being misled as to the origin of a product. So if you
>   were making a product, and you used a Stack Exchange name or logo in
>   your product (or in its advertising) in such a way that would mislead
>   someone into thinking that your product was owned by, operated by,
>   endorsed by, or in any way part of Stack Exchange Inc., you would be
>   violating the trademark and this would not be legal.
>
> Our logo images and site names are copyrighted. Any content on the
>   Stack Exchange Network not contributed by users is copyrighted.
>   Copyright is different than trademark. Ordinarily you couldn't copy
>   it. But if you were writing a news story or blog post about a Stack
>   Exchange site, reproducing the logo image would almost certainly be
>   considered "fair use" and allowed under trademark law because you were
>   not using it "in trade."

Other unofficial communities, such as arqade have [used alternative logos](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/gamingstackexchange) for their purposes.

Perhaps an artisitic member could produce something :)

Comment: Would the picture of the T-shirt not be a nice alternative?

Comment: @Bernhard I'm not a lawyer, but the impression I get is you're still using their logo :/

Comment: What if you find some hot chick to pose in it? :)

Comment: @Bernhard You're sexist.

Comment: @tohecz No, I am not. Notify me on chat if you want to convince me.

Comment: @Bernhard Sorry, I meant it with a sarcastic tone and not really seriously, I just forgot that you can't hear my tone of voice :)

Comment: @tohecz Hehe, if you want a hot guy or transgender in the shirt, it is also ok ;)

Comment: @Bernhard: My girlfriend is hot... and she has worn the  T much more than me... as pajamas!